# Apache Beam job hangs up when submitted via spark-submit

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-beam, spark-submit

I am just trying to execute Apache Beam example code in local spark setup. I generated the source and built the package as mentioned in [this page](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/). And submitted the jar using spark-submit as below,

```
$ ~/spark/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount --master local target/word-count-beam-0.1.jar --runner=SparkRunner --inputFile=pom.xml --output=counts
```

The code gets submitted and starts to execute. But gets stuck at step `Evaluating ParMultiDo(ExtractWords)`. Below is the log after submitting the job.

Am not able to find any error message. Can someone please help in finding whats wrong?

Edit: I also tried using below command,

```
~/spark/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount --master spark://Quartics-MacBook-Pro.local:7077 target/word-count-beam-0.1.jar --runner=SparkRunner --inputFile=pom.xml --output=counts
```

The job is now stuck at `INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.0.2:59049 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, 192.168.0.2, 59049, None)`. Attached the screenshots of Spark History & Dashboard below.The dashboard shows the job is running, but no progress at all.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a version issue. I was able to run the job in Spark 1.6.3. Thanks to all the people who just down voted this question without explanations.